# How does hashcat figure out the SHA CRYPT ROUNDS on a Linux password

Tags: hash, password-cracking, hashcat

A part of my `/etc/login.defs` file looks like this:

```
ENCRYPT_METHOD SHA512

# Define the number of SHA rounds.
# If not specified, the libc will choose the default number of rounds (5000).
# The values must be inside the 1000-999999999 range.
# If only one of the MIN or MAX values is set, then this value will be used.
# If MIN > MAX, the highest value will be used.
#
# SHA_CRYPT_MIN_ROUNDS 5000

SHA_CRYPT_MAX_ROUNDS 6000
```

From what I understand of this, is that the password will go through 6000 rounds of hash.

Now, when I used a tool like `hashcat` how do I tell it that the hash has gone through 'x' number of rounds.

I am able to use hashcat like so: `hashcat -m 1800 -a 0 -o found.txt hash.txt rockyou.txt` and it is still able to find it. Is it able to figure out the number of rounds by itself?

**Edit**: I just found out that the Linux box wasn't actually using 6000 rounds of hash, although I thought I had configured it to use 6000 rounds. Instead it was just 5000.

With some Python code, I was able to replicate the "SHA512" password encryption in Linux:

```
from passlib.hash import sha512_crypt
sha512_crypt.encrypt("testing123",rounds=6000,salt="6EGwX1iP")
```

The resulting hash is `$6$rounds=6000$6EGwX1iP$oMerxGPimb/4ZXcI0Vbt87sNfw07eh7VPzcQwHOls8t3hLYGLQR0KjncrpyAjLTfPC3Fj7jhFoZKeuPRfTbJa/`

This string of course has the number of rounds which can be passed to `hashcat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: I saw that you found your answer, but I'll add it here for completeness sake. (And I already had this written down).

---

Hashcat doesn't guess the # of rounds, and the amount of rounds specified in your `/etc/login.defs` isn't properly applied.

I took an example from my Linux box:

> $6$elIIOT8d$lXVE7ZxTaBnvyi3kgrVGOpq.I/tQU9CN.G2FgpcjyxovibRB1TjDbk7NFkOwo7ySt.w8BwnacxQ0876/hz6l//

This is the same as:

> $6**$rounds=5000**&elIIOT8d$lXVE7ZxTaBnvyi3kgrVGOpq.I/tQU9CN.G2FgpcjyxovibRB1TjDbk7NFkOwo7ySt.w8BwnacxQ0876/hz6l//

If the amount of rounds was properly set, you would see a different number instead of 5000 in the hash.

### Linux

On my box running Kali Linux I was able to specify the number of rounds by going to the `/etc/pam.d/common-password` and finding the line (line 25 in my case):

> password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure sha512

I appended "rounds=1234" to it:

> password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure sha512 rounds=1234

saved and created a user:

`$> adduser test3`

And ended up with this in my `/etc/shadow`-file:

`$>tail --lines=1 /etc/shadow`

> test3:$6$**rounds=1234**$SzWcxuIH$YX1QDmE1PG7grJ/4rJ8LkwggmEffoo9vUCuPAhL3x2sBQZJ8n2a2OeHpFEKaWDH2o.NGYwbLFZNabfOQlQuZ21:16627:0:99999:7:::

### Hashcat

You can manually specify how many iterations Hashcat should do by appending rounds=[# of iterations] after the signature, e.g:

> $6**$rounds=5000**&elIIOT8d$lXVE7ZxTaBnvyi3kgrVGOpq.I/tQU9CN.G2FgpcjyxovibRB1TjDbk7NFkOwo7ySt.w8BwnacxQ0876/hz6l//

This will, however, be automatically applied if the amount of rounds != 5000, in `/etc/shadow`

Answer (score 0):

Neither `SHA_CRYPT_MIN_ROUNDS` nor `SHA_CRYPT_MAX_ROUNDS` from `login.defs` should be applied at all in this case. As you can find in the `man login.defs` section of this parameter:

> Note: This only affect the generation of group passwords. The
> generation of user passwords is done by PAM and subject to the PAM
> configuration. It is recommended to set this variable consistently
> with the PAM configuration.